# detect when asynchronus tasks is done

Tags: javascript, sqlite, asynchronous

I want to detect when this list of asynchronous operations is totally done, and that to use the inserted entries in other operation.

```
    var peers = this.response["peers"];
    $.each(peers, function(key, value) {
        that.database.transaction(function(tx) {
            var user_id = parseInt(value["user_id"]);
            var username = value["username"];
            var picture = value["picture"];
            var date_of_birth = value["date_of_birth"];
            var score = parseInt(value["score"]);
            var country = value["country"];
            var last_seen = value["last_seen"];
            var is_favorite = value["is_favorite"];
            var is_match = value["is_match"];
            var is_blocked = value["is_blocked"];
            var is_auto_match = value["is_auto_match"];
            var is_profile_viewer = value["is_profile_viewer"];
            var sql = "insert into users(user_id,username,picture,";
            sql += "date_of_birth,score,country,last_seen,is_blocked,";
            sql += "is_favorite,is_match,is_auto_match,is_profile_viewer)";
            sql += "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            tx.executeSql(sql, [user_id, username, picture, date_of_birth, score, country, last_seen, is_blocked, is_favorite, is_match, is_auto_match, is_profile_viewer]);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you use any async libraries like `async`, or `q`?

Comment: no I don't use any async library, but sqlite transaction is an async method

Comment: There are more than one calls in that loop which require callbacks. You should look into using jQuery's [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)

Comment: In fact I am not using jquery, I am using appframework for mobiles

Comment: Damn... `$.each` just looked so familiar. Are you sure it's not jQuery? You should still use a promise library then, it makes code organization easier.

Comment: Thanks but in fact appframework is much better form mobiles

Comment: @Moussawi7 AppFramework can work in tandem with jQuery, according to their website. Otherwise this could get unnecessarily messy

Comment: Interesting, they have a *very* similar API than jQuery has. But again, add a promise library and be happy about better code organization.

Comment: @FelixKling Looking at GitHub, they're using parts of Zepto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use any async techniques, then you can do this

```
var peers = this.response["peers"];
var total = peers.length;
$.each(peers, function(key, value) {
    that.database.transaction(function(tx) {
        ...
        tx.executeSql(sql, [...], function() {
            total -= 1;
            if (!total) {
                otherOperation(...); // Invoke the operation after all data done
            }
        });
    });
});
```